# Solve system of equations: 2 differential, 1 quadratic in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

Write a Matlab(or other) code for solving the system numericaly:
w'(t)=dw(t)/dt;

```
w'(t)=3*w(t)*y(t),
y'(t)=8*w(t)*y(t),
t^2=9+w(t)+y(t)
```

I don't know how to use ode45 for this as t has 2 solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to solve this numerically? For a numeric solution, you would need at least an initial condition, i.e. `w(0), y0)`.

Note that, by comparing the first two equations: `8w'(t) = 3y'(t)`

Then, derive the third equation to obtain:

`2t = w'(t)+y'(t)`

This implies :

`8*3*2t = 8*3*w'(t)+8*3*y'(t)`

`48t = 8*3*w'(t)+8*8*w'(t)`

`48t = 88*w'(t)`

`6t = 11*w'(t)`

Thus `w'(0)=0` and `y'(0)=0`.

Therefore, from the first equation: `w(0)*y(0)=0`.

Because the equations are symmetric, there are two solutions as you mention. Assume `w(0)=0`, then from the third equation, 'y(0)=-9'. And from `6t = 11*w'(t)` we have `w(t)=(6/11)t`, and `y(t)=-9+(48/33)t`.

The other solution is `y(t)=(6/11)t`, and `w(t)=-9+(48/33)t`.

Comment: These equations are just an example of what I need, in reality, I have 38 equation, I need a way to insert them to ode45 or similar, they can't be solved analytically, I have initial conditions but I don't know what to do with [t0  tf] because t itself is a variable which I need to solve in these system

Comment: How come the time is a variable to be solved for? Can you start learning how to use `ode45` by setting `tspan = [0,1]`? Maybe later you can use some numerical method to solve for your time span.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the time that 2 freely rotating and moving ellipsoids will collide

Comment: Then set `tspan` to start at 0 and end at some educated-guess number. Use a post-processing routine to check if the ellipsoid collide, if they don't but are approaching, increase the time and simulate/integrate the equations from your earlier guess until a next one. If the ellipsoids are moving apart, abort the loop and conclude they'll never collide.

Comment: Can I use ode45 options=odeset('events',h(t,s)) and to test if the ellipsoid collide in check?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea,  you would likely call it as `options = odeset('events', @h)`, as the argument needs to be a function handle, and not a function call.